# How to change the cscfg file used in Azure deployment from Visual Studio Team Services build?

Tags: git, azure, azure-worker-roles, azure-devops

How do I specify which .cscfg file should be used in an Azure deployment triggered by an automated build in Visual Studio Team Services?

Here's my current situation:

- I have a solution using Git in Visual Studio Team Services that contains an Azure web role and an Azure worker role.
- In the solution I've set up two `.cscfg` files - one for my Azure staging environment (`ServiceConfiguration.CloudTest.cscfg`), and one for my Azure production environment (`ServiceConfiguration.Cloud.cscfg`).
- I can manually trigger a deployment from Visual Studio to either environment
- I have an automated build in VS Team Services using `GitContinuousDeploymentTemplate.12.xaml` That deploys to my integration test environment, but apparently applies the `ServiceConfiguration.Cloud.cscfg` file. Makes sense, I suppose, since that's the default `.cscfg` file name

However, I can't see where in the build process I can specify a different `.cscfg` file name. Is there a way I can specify which `.cscfg` file to use in the deployment process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the msbuild arguments with the following property:

```
/p:TargetProfile=TFSBuildProfile
```

I am doing that in our automated builds for tfs online. Then it uses the ServiceConfiguration.TFSBuildProfile.cscfg when building.

Comment: Thanks, now that I know what I'm looking for, this is documented in http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-dotnet-continuous-delivery/. My relative inexperience with the build templates gave me no clue where to plug that into the build definition, though!